# Understanding custom comparators in C++

Tags: c++, string, compare, string-comparison

```cpp
static bool cmp(string &a,string &b)
{
    if(a.size()==b.size())
    {
        return a<b;
    }
    return a.size()<b.size();
}
```

This is a custom comparator to compare two strings that consist of big numbers, like "3922" and "12929", and compare them to see which is larger. However, I don't understand why when `a.size() == b.size()` we return `a < b`?

Comment: A smaller string is considered to be less than a larger string.   But, if the sizes are equal, it is necessary to compare the content.  The test `a < b` ensures things such as "1234" less than "5678" or "abcd" less than "fghi".  Without the function would return `false`  when comparing "1234" and "5678" (in either order).   If used in standard algorithms such a comparator would cause undefined behaviour (since standard algorithms require a comparator to describe at least a strict-weak ordering).

Comment: Do you have an alternative in mind? Perhaps instead of analyzing this comparison, you should try to write your own (from scratch). Even if you don't succeed, you might learn enough from the process to figure out the given function.

Answer (score 0):

if statement will execute only if the size of both strings is the same.(i.e "232" is equal to "934". but it will not execute for string-like ("2342", "234242").

and in the if statement you are comparing strings, not integers. so if want to compare integers then covert them first.

Answer (score 0):

Common algorithms in the standard library like `std::lower_bound` and `std::sort` make use of just one comparison function assumed to provide the result of `a < b`, which is enough to make all the other comparisons (if they need to test equality they can do `!(a < b || b < a)`, for instance).

If this custom function didn't check the length of the strings, "1000" would come before "50" in lexicographical order, which is what `std::string`'s `operator<(...)` uses (and what is used in that function when their length is equal).